# How do I display all categories on a page with a corresponding image?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to display a list of all the categories from a product custom post on a "product" page with thumbnail images. What would the code be to do that and could I use the category description as the image source for the thumbnail?

I'm not sure what code I should show but I have a wordpress theme I'm trying to modify. I need a page that says "Product Categories" That displays all the different categories of products I've tagged. So I tagged say "bikes" and "cars" as "transportation" I need to display transportation with a thumbnail that represents transportation that links to the category page.

Comment: you should provide additional details, e.g. the wordpress plugin used or sourcecode samples.

Comment: This question is so out of context.